# jQuery Apple-like image fade-in effect

Tags: jquery, fadein

When you go to http://www.apple.com/mac/, you'll see the above products are faded into the page with some kind of effect. Is there a jQuery plugin which can do something similar like that fade-in?

Comment: that's more like a slide in than fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle I put together that is similar: http://jsfiddle.net/33sN4/1/

You wouldn't really need a plugin, though I'm sure there's one out there...

You just need to itterate through the objects and delay the fadeIn (or slide, or animate... whatever effect you choose):

```
$(function(){   

    $('.region').each(function(index){
        $(this).delay(index*1000).fadeIn(500);
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery contains methods to produce similar effects.  You can use .fadeIn(secs) and .fadeOut(secs) to do what you need.  You can also use .anmiate() to animate CSS properties.  For a full description of jQuery's capabilities, view the jQuery Effects documentation:

[documentation link](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

To view some plugins that showcase the fadeIn/fadeOut slide effect, view

[plugin demos](http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin for jQuery.

You can use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to acheive the desired result. You can even tweak the timing to alter the affect to your liking.

eg.

```
$('#mac').css({
    left: 0,
    opacity: 0
}).delay(500).animate({
    left: 50,
    opacity: 1,
    queue: false
}, 'fast');
```

Working example, click on an image to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/cfgyhdou/